# Relationship between Dirichlet character and Legrendre symbol

Tags: number-theory, intuition, legendre-symbol, dirichlet-character

I'm wondering whether you always can express a non trivial Dirichlet character by a Legendre symbol. And in case so, how would one explicitly do that? Or how does one connect the two things?

Comment: You have included little to no context for your Question, and as a result the Answer you got was "maybe a bit too high."  For the sake of expediting responses that are useful to you, please be more generous in framing the problem (why it interests you, how you encountered it, what you tried before posting, etc.) so that Readers don't have to guess where your level of studies ought to be assumed.

Answer (score 2):

Only $\pm 1$ valued Dirichlet characters are products of Legendre symbols $(n/p)$  (well almost all of them as there is a problem for the 3 quadratic characters $\bmod 8$)

If $\chi$ is a $\pm 1$ valued character of least period $2N+1$ then it is a product of $\pm 1$ valued characters of period $p^k \| 2N+1$ and each of them is either the trivial character $1_{p\ \nmid\ n}=(n/p)^2$ or the Legendre symbol $(n/p)$.

Then look at $$\chi(5n)=0,\chi(5n+1)=1,\chi(5n+2)=i,\chi(5n+3)=-i,\chi(5n+4)=-1$$

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to understand. Your level of explaining is maybe a bit too high for me. What I read is that, if a Dirichet character only takes values $\pm 1$ then it can $\textit{always (?)}$ be written as a product of Legendre symbols. 

For the example in the bottom I see a Dirichlet character mod 5, but it can't (?) be written as a product of Legendre symbols. (We also have that $\left( \frac{2}{5} \right)=-1 \neq i$)

Comment: Something different happens if $\chi$ doesn't have an odd period. Which part exactly is unclear to you ?

Comment: What do you mean by the symbol $||$ in "$p^k||2N+1$"? And can you give an example of a 3 quadratic character mod 8? And what I'm I to see from your example? That the Dirichlet character $\chi$ mod 5 can't be written as a Legrendre symbol?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I'm a slow learner

Comment: $\chi_5$ is complex valued, clearly not a product of $\pm 1$ valued characters (such as $(n/p)$). $\Bbb{Z/8Z}^\times$ is generated by $3$ and $-1$, each of order 2, so a character must send them to $\pm 1$ and each of the 4 choices is possible, giving 1 trivial character and 3 quadratic characters. It is because of these that we need the Kronecker symbol.